# Cannot use axios on localhost

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, axios

I'm trying to test my code with axios on local but i get that error `Object { message: "Network Error", name: "AxiosError", code: "ERR_NETWORK", etc...`
I tried to change adress to full http://localhost/contact/send & again but with ip... nothing of these works.

Can someone help me fix that issue

My code:

```js
export default {
    name: 'App',
    components: {},
    data() {
        return {
            name: '',
            email: '',
            message: '',
            allowSend: false,
            sent: false
        }
    },
    methods: {
        sendMessage() {
            axios.post('/contact/send', {
                name: this.name,
                email: this.email,
                msg: this.message
            })

            this.sent = true

            setTimeout(() => {
                this.sent = false
            }, 3000)
        },
        checkProps() {
            let nameCheck = false
            let emailCheck = false
            let msgCheck = false

            if(this.name !== '') nameCheck = true
            if(validator(this.email)) emailCheck = true
            if(this.message !== '') msgCheck = true

            if(nameCheck && emailCheck && msgCheck) this.allowSend = true
        }
    },
    template
}
```

Comment: check url address once . If possible put the screenshot of network request from network tab .

Comment: Do you have a server running on localhost that handles those URLs? Sounds like you don't.

Comment: I have localhost nodejs server